# How to check method_defined? from a module thats used in class with a method defined after the module is included

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, module, mixins

How can I define a module that checks the existence of an instance method in the class the module is used. The module is normally included at the start of the file while methods are defined afterwards. I'm using Rails.

A module with a hook

```rb
module MyModule
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  included do
    raise "Foo" if method_defined? :bar
  end 
end
```

A `Foo` error is never raised in the following code, how can I get this to raise the error?

```rb
class MyClass 
   include MyModule

   def bar
     puts "Hello from Bar"
   end 
end
```

A `Foo` error IS raised in the following code:

```rb
class MyOtherClass 
   def bar
     puts "Hello from Bar"
   end 

   include MyModule
end
```

Comment: Ruby executes instructions in a class definition, just like any other instruction sequence, one by one. At the time `include MyModule`, `MyClass` does not have `bar` yet. You would need a time machine to know that `bar` will be defined in the future.

Comment: Write an exception block. If the method is not defined it will raise an error so you can rescue it with some code block

Answer (score 1):

This is a pure-Ruby answer. I don't know if Rails supports callbacks that are not supported by Ruby that would be useful here.

As @Amadan notes, the module is not a mind-reader; to see an instance method defined on the class the method needs to be defined before the module is included. The method [Module#included](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Module.html#method-i-included) takes as an argument the module in which it being included. It needs that because `self` is `MyModule` when that method is executed.

```
module MyModule
  def self.included(mod)
    puts "self = #{self}"
    puts ":bar is defined" if mod.method_defined? :bar
    puts ":foo is defined" if mod.method_defined? :foo
    puts ":goo is defined" if mod.method_defined? :goo
  end
  def goo
  end  
end
```

```
class MyClass 
  def bar
  end 
  include MyModule
end
```

prints

```
self = MyModule
:bar is defined
:goo is defined
```

Note that `Module#included` is executed after the instance method defined in `MyModule` (`goo`) is included in `MyClass`.

Comment: `MyModule` need not be a mind reader only a watcher. One could use [`Module#method_added`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.1/Module.html#method-i-method_added) to watch for `bar`'s definition and raise in that event.